# jQuery multiple reoccurrence replace innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script works for the replace with jQuery in innerHTML.

**HTML code**

```
<input type="submit" name="replace" id="replace" value="Replace" />

<div class="my_div">Default1 content1</div>
<div class="my_div">Default2 content2</div>
```

**java script**

```
$('#replace').click(function() {
   $('.my_div').html(function( idx, oldHtml){
      return oldHtml.replace(/Default1|content1|Default2|content2/gi, 'symbol1');
   });
});
```

But I couldn't modify the script for multiple unique replacement. Example I want to replace

Default1 to symbol1

Default2 to symbol2

content1 to symbol3

content2 to symbol4

the following doesn't work

```
$('#replace').click(function() {
   $('.my_div').html(function( idx, oldHtml){
      return oldHtml.replace(/Default1/gi, 'symbol1');
      return oldHtml.replace(/Default2/gi, 'symbol2');
      return oldHtml.replace(/content1/gi, 'symbol3');
      return oldHtml.replace(/content2/gi, 'symbol4');
   });
});
```

Also I had early script based on id attribute, which is more than 500 replace lines. Is it possible that I can include similar structure in this new jQuery class attribute?

```
var str=document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Default1","symbol1");
var n=str.replace("Default2","symbol2");
document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML=n;
}
```

Thanks a lot, you guys helped me a lot. :)

Comment: if you need 500 replace lines there are likely far simpler ways like looping over array, or possibly identifiers in markup that would simplify the whole process. Some better real world examples and markup would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1 :**

Replace

```
return oldHtml.replace(/Default1/gi, 'symbol1');
return oldHtml.replace(/Default2/gi, 'symbol2');
return oldHtml.replace(/content1/gi, 'symbol3');
return oldHtml.replace(/content2/gi, 'symbol4');
```

with

```
return oldHtml.replace(/Default1/gi, 'symbol1')
    .replace(/Default2/gi, 'symbol2')
    .replace(/content1/gi, 'symbol3')
    .replace(/content2/gi, 'symbol4');
```

**Question 2 :**

Replace

```
var str=document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Default1","symbol1");
var n=str.replace("Default2","symbol2");
document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML=n;
```

with

```
var $div = $('#my_id');
$div.html(
    $div.html().replace("Default1","symbol1")
    .replace("Default2","symbol2")
);
```

(if you use jQuery, no need for those getElementById)